# setting up 301 redirects: dynamic urls to static urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web, templates, http-status-code-301

We are currently using a template-based website and are hoping to move to a site with static urls.  Our domain will stay the same.  I understand that using 301 redirects in a .htaccess file is the preferred method -- and the one that has the highest chance of preserving our google rankings.

I am still new at all this and am having a hard time figuring out the proper way to code it all.

Over a hundred of our pages are indexed.  They all have a similar URL but with different pageIDs:
    http://www.realestate-bigbear.com/Nav.aspx/Page=%2fPageManager%2fDefault.aspx%2fPageID%3d2020765

Some link out to provided content, ex.
    /RealEstateNews/Default.aspx

Then there are many that flow from the main featured listings page:
    /ListNow/Default.aspx
Down to all the specific properties.. where the PropertyId changes
    /ListNow/Property.aspx?PropertyID=2048098

would a simple set of codes work... like the following....
        redirect 301 /Nav.aspx/Page=%2fPageManager%2fDefault.aspx%2fPageID%3d2020765 www.realestate.bigbear.com/SearchBigBearMLS.htm

or do I need to do something entirely different?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you are trying to do.  For example with what you posted, ALL of the previously unique pages are going to go to a single page.  I don't think that is what you want to do, as in the end, that is most likely going to reduce the amount of information that is listed in Google.

Typically you want to map any/all pages that you want to keep around, you can condense some, but if there is still a truly unique page for each content item, you will want to be sure that you have mapped it out.